Liénard-Chipart Stability Criterion. Who is Chipart?
Who is M. H. Chipart? I cannot find any information about this scientist.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Chipart_criterion
has a reference to French Math Journal Liénard, A.; Chipart, M. H. (1914). "Sur le signe de la partie réelle des racines d'une équation algébrique".
https://archive.org/details/gantmacher-the-theory-of-matrices-vol-2-1959/page/221/mode/2up?view=theater
Gantmacher's text has something about it:
This circumstance was investigated by the French mathematicians Liénard and Chipart in 1914...


I searched "french mathematician chipart"  but it changed the name to clipart, which are cartoons or other images.

Maybe Albert Henri CHIPART (1871-1941) also called Henri Chipart (1871-1941).

I believe I've found an entry for him at Annales.org:  Albert Henri Chipart (1871-1941).
I say believe, because the citation in the OP is for "M. H. Chipart" rather than "A. H. Chipart". This discrepancy is not clarified by going back to the original publication (available here), which seemingly only provides the surnames. The use of "M. H. Chipart" is common among citations to the Liénard-Chipart criterion, but an exception to this (and where I found the name) is found here.
As evidence in favor of this attribution, Albert Henri Chipart and Alfred-Marie Liénard were both Parisian physicists in the early 20th century. Indeed, they each had positions as professors of industrial electricity at both École des Mines de Paris and l'Ecole des mines de Saint-Etienne, albeit with limited direct overlap. Another curious point is that Chipart's entry at BNF does feature the "M. H. Chipart" initials, under the section "Documents sur Henri Chipart (1871-1941)". I suspect the document referenced there, a 1930 notice on his scientific works, would likely clarify the matter; however, it seems to be a printed work and thus outside my access.

And I swear I was writing up the above post before I saw Mauro's comment above...

Nice work. Might it be that the first initial was misread at some point and it stuck? A scripty A and M could be misconstrued. Something similar happened with one of my ancestors in the 1830 or so census.

The pages of the Annales of Ecole des Mines ends up by a caricature (from a student) saying "I am Mr Chipart, successor of Lienard".

@Taladris good catch! That seems to confirm it, though it makes me wish there was more of an account of their evident relationship.

M. H. Chipart could stand for "Monsieur Henri Chipart". Skipping the first name is not that unusual at the time, (Wilhelm) Martin Kutta for instance did it as well in his publications.

I wondered if that could be the case, but didn't know enough about French academic customs to confidently speculate.
